Unable to connect to cloud datastore from local legacy project based on python2.7 and django 1.4
I have a django==1.4 project (python==2.7) that I wanted to run and make some changes. I am unable to connect to cloud datastore from my local codebase. Right now, when I run the project using dev_appserver.py like:
dev_appserver.py PROJECT_NAME --enable_console
It runs three different servers:

API server on localhost:RANDOM_PORT
Module default at localhost:8080
Admin server at localhost:8000

Now I visit http://localhost:8000/console and browse interative console and then run some python script like importing User model and fetching if there is anything there or not. And there isn't, why? Because it connects to the local AppIdentityServiceStub. And obviously there isn't any data unless I create some.
Now I want to connect this codebase to my cloud datastore and I have tried different implementations that are already on stackoverflow and other platforms. One of them is setting environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to a keyfile.json that service account provides. I have the keyfile.json and I have set it to env variable but still I get connected to local datastore which has no data. Let me know if I am running this project wrong? or is there any other way to connect to cloud datastore from my local?
Also, one more thing, when I do not set the env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS it shows this WARNING:
WARNING  2024-04-22 08:12:02,588 app_identity_stub.py:206] An exception has been encountered when attempting to use Application Default Credentials: File /Users/USER/keyfile.json (pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!. Falling back on dummy AppIdentityServiceStub.

And when I set it to keyfile.json, this warning goes away but still this isn't connecting to the cloud datastore. What could be the reason? What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to run this code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

What version of gcloud CLI are you running? I asked 'cos from gcloud CLI 468, you can't use dev_appserver.py to run your app locally for runtimes that have reached end of life and that includes Python 2.7 (see reference)

Yes, it has reached its end of life support but from here(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#before_you_begin) I got the google-cloud-sdk zip and I am using it to run my application along with glcoud cli.

You're using an older Google Cloud SDK zip with dev_appserver.py to develop a Python 2.7 Django 1.4 project. While this works, the legacy SDK might lack security updates and compatibility with newer gcloud CLI versions. Upgrade to the latest Cloud SDK using gcloud components update for better security and features.

Yes, @Chanpols, you are so right. We are setting up the upgrade of the whole code and gcloud but right now we have to make it running.

I've updated my answer. You also didn't answer the question of if you redeployed your App after specifying builtins in your app.yaml


What you need is remote_api. The documentation says

You can use the Remote API to access your application's data store from an app running on your local machine, or from a local interactive Remote API shell.


According to that documentation, you'll have to deploy your application after enabling remote_api. Unfortunately, by default, you can't do that for Python27 since it's reached end of support. To be able to deploy runtimes which have reached end of support, see this documentation


Update
If you use builtins, you can only access remote_api at the path /_ah/remote_api i.e. for remote_api to work, you need to use paths like -
<projectid>.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api/


Tried adding `builtins:

remote_api: ontoo inapp.yaml` long ago too. But it also didn't work.


@AkifHussain: Did you redeploy your App to production? You have to do that for remote_api to work. If you did and still weren't able to connect to production datastore, include the relevant code snippet in your post (the question you asked).
